# Help with product maps in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, product-space

Let $A, B, X, Y$ be topological spaces.

Given two functions $f : A \to B$ and $g : X \to Y $, let
$f \times g : A × X \to B \times Y$, $ (f \times g)(a, x) = (f(a), g(x))$.

can you help me to show that if f and g is cont. then fxg is too

and if the sets A,B is non-empty, then it holds the other way around too.

I'm pretty stuck.. can you please help me?

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqaDX.png)

> To show the statement, I will use Theorem 4.1. If I can show that $f\times g(\overline{S\times T})\subseteq \overline{f\times g(S\times T)}$ for a subset $S\times T\subseteq A\times X$.
>
> Take a $(b,y)\in f\times g(\overline{S\times T})$. Then there exists a $s\in\overline S$ and $t\in\overline T$ such that $f(s)=b$ and $g(t)=y$.
>   We know that both $f$ and $g$ is continuous, so from 4.1 we get $f(s)\in\overline B$ and $g(t)\in\overline Y$, and then $(b,y)\in \overline{f\times g (S\times T)}$. And from 4.1 we get that $f\times g$ is continuous.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: hi Mees. I have just added my solution to (a). Could u maybe give your opinion on that? My theoreme 4.1 says that
f is continuous iff. f(closure(A)) is in Closure(f(A))

Comment: I just saw that i miss a bar over f×g(SxT) in the last part

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). To help you get started, I have retyped the text from your picture.

Comment: thank u. Can anybody verify my answer?

Comment: You might also have a look at some related questions: [Continuity of cartesian product of functions between topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673098), [Characterization of the Product Topology as the finest in terms of a continuous function into the product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1909921).

Comment: There are several problems with your attempt. You are using result which characterizes continuity using the condition $f\times g(\overline C)\subseteq \overline{f\times g(C)}$ for *any* subset $C\subseteq A\times X$. You are working with sets of the form $C=S\times T$ instead. Also you wrote that you are using $f(s)\in\overline B$ and $g(t)\in\overline Y$. Since $\overline B=B$ and $\overline Y=Y$ this does not give you any new information, so I assume you wanted to write something else there.

Comment: why is \overline(B)=B and \overline(Y)=Y? 
My goal is to show that if, (b,y) is in f(\overline(SxT)) then (b,y) is in \overline(f(SxT))

Comment: @MarcHansen If your most recent was addressed to me, you should use `@username` so that I get the notification. For any topological space you have $\overline X=X$ (and $\overline\emptyset=\emptyset$. So this is true also for topological space $B$ and $Y$. (Maybe you wanted to use $f(S)$ instead of $B$ and $g(T)$ instead of $Y$?)

Comment: @MartinSleziak ah okay, i see. So if i say f(s)$\in$$\overline{f(S)}$ and g(t)$\in$$\overline{g(T)}$? then my answer is better?

Comment: In that way you would get $(b,y)\in\overline{f(S)}\times\overline{g(T)}$. Together with the fact hat $\overline{M\times N} =\overline M \times \overline N$ this seems to go in the right direction.

Comment: The closure approach is too messy IMHO. The categorical approach via the universal property seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

By the universal property of products, a function : $F: Z \to X \times Y$ is continuous iff $\pi_X \circ F$ and $\pi_Y \circ F$ (the  compositions with the continuous projections) are all (both) continuous.

This allows us to quickly solve the problem, applied to the product $B \times Y$ and $Z = A \times X$: $$\pi_B \circ (f \times g) = f\circ \pi_A$$ where the right hand side is continuous as a composition of continuous maps. The identity can be seen by evaluating both sides on an arbitary point $(a,x)$ and both expressions become $f(a)$.

Also $$\pi_Y \circ (f \times g) = g\circ \pi_X$$ and so both compositions with projections of $f \times g$ are continuous and so $f \times g$ is continuous.

On the other hand suppose that $f \times g$ is continuous, and fix $x_0 \in X$ and
define $i: A \to A \times X$ by $i(a) = (a,x_0)$. As $\pi_A \circ i$ is the identity on $A$ (hence continuous) and $\pi_X \circ i$ is a constant map with the value $x_0$ (also continuous) the trusted universal property tells us that $i$ is continuous, and then note that $f = \pi_B \circ (f \times g) \circ i$ and then $f$ can be written as the continuous composition of continuous maps.

That $g$ is also continuous can be seen with the same idea and another embedding (now using a fixed $a_0 \in A$) from $X$ into $A \times X$.

Comment: okay thanks for your time. Have you looked at (b)? For me, that was the hardest one

Comment: @EstebanCambiasso it’s already part of the solution after “ on the other hand”.